# Generated .pom not including transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, pom.xml, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

Having a bit of an issue where my generated .pom (using Gradle v4.10.3 & the maven-publish gradle plugin) is not including transitive dependencies. From what I've read, it should be reading the project dependencies and including them (I think!) instead of me having to manually declare them in the .pom. I did look at the documentation for the Pom object and did not see any methods that could declare transitive dependencies.

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1822620

Here is a snippet of my project root's build.gradle.kts file, and the code from my subproject's build.gradle.kts file (`android-core`). As you can see, subproject `android-core` depends on subproject `core`, but it is not being declared as such when I generate the .pom.

Is there a setting I'm supposed to set somewhere that tells the .pom where to find the dependencies? Or am I going about this the completely wrong way? Any and all help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have this in my pipeline log file, which might explain why `android-core` can't see `core` as a depdency (maybe?)

```
22:47:03.531 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :generatePomFileForMaven-android-corePublication (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.

22:47:06.746 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :generatePomFileForMaven-android-localPublication (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.

22:47:23.416 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :generatePomFileForMaven-corePublication (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.

22:47:25.259 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :generatePomFileForMaven-learningPublication (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.
```

I have no idea why they would be generating the Pom out of order, however, because it is going through a list with a pre-defined order.

**EDIT: SOLUTION** Okay, the above *was* the issue - the uploading order, I think because the Maven Publish plugin is uploading asynchronously and the contents of `core` took longer to resolve because it has more dependencies & is larger overall.  I switched my publishing to be on a per subproject basis and explicitly called one after the other in  the CI scripting file and it now works as intended with all dependencies.

**side note:** When I switched to individual subproject method of publishing I did have to switch the `maven-publish` plugin to the `android-maven-publish` plugin to get it to support publishing (because you cannot include the `java` plugin within an android project if you also have `com.android.library`). I also had to switch the `from(components["java"])` to `from(components["android"])`.

I don't think this is the best way to do this but at this point, at least it works. I'll try to optimize it better in the future (and any actual answers are welcome!)